# convert from datetime to another locale datetime in java

Tags: java, javascript

My client javascript app and server app run in different countries. I need to synchronize events. In other words client app send a url string representing local datetime, something like:

```
date = new Date() # Mon Jul 22 2013 16:28:34 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

On the server ( linode ) side, is running a small application written in java. I need to convert this string in a local server side-machine datetime, and store to rdbms via hibernate so that a cron or clock-like app can read this date from table and activate a new event and synchronize to remote. this must happen exactly on the date indicated by client. Which is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean time zone or locale (format)? They are completely different.

Comment: I want to activate the event on server side exactly when at the client side datetime is "Mon Jul 22 2013 16:28:34 GMT+0200 (CEST)". Actually I can send number of milliseconds or whatever; I am interested only to server conversion solution.

Comment: So you're asking how to parse a string?

Answer (score 0):

if both have correct time and time zone, **Date** in milliseconds will be same for both server and client, no matter in what time zone they are .

Send the date from client in milliseconds and accept it on serverside in a `java.sql.Date(long)` constructor.
You mentioned javascript in tags. So Date can be sent through javascript using `new Date();` and can be accepted by server using

```
new java.sql.Date(client_date);
```

In milliseconds, the client time would be converted to appropriate server time.
If client time is not properly set, for that, you can use the *time difference* in milliseconds 
like -

```
long time_difference= new Date()-new Date(client_date);
long server_time_of_execution=new Date(Client_date_to_execute).getTime()+time_difference;
```